# ckan local installation, 500 error on solr JSP support not configured

Tags: solr, jetty, ubuntu-14.04, ckan

I am trying to install CKAN on my local computer using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I followed the instructions for installing from source found [here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) and I try to check if solr is running by visiting http://localhost:8983/solr/.

I can see that Jetty is running because when I visit http://localhost:8983 I see that it is up.
I added the jdk as follows:
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64`

I am getting a 500 error when i try to open the solr page:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /solr/index.jsp. Reason:
>
> JSP support not configured
>
> Powered by Jetty://

Any ideas? Should I redo the whole thing from the start?

**Edit/Update**
I just couldn't do anything with this installation. The bigger problem was that installation files were meshed up! I tried to install tomcat/solr instead of jetty/solr and things went sour. So I just created a VM and did a fresh install there. For anyone interested I did a tomcat/solr installation following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04) and a CKAN installation following [this](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) (with out of course the solr instructions). Also, for some reason the CKAN installation has commented out the solr URL, so even if it is right, I had to delete the comment.

Comment: which version of solr you are using?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti i am not sure how to check for the version. i havent download anything manually. it auto install using `sudo apt-get install....solr-jetty`

Comment: Solr admin page is located here: http://{host-name-or-ip}:{port}/solr/admin, click on the info... http://10.55.36.14:8080/solr/{if you have created core}/admin/registry.jsp...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti the problem is that i can't access localhost:8983/solr. So i can't see the version from there

Answer (score 4):

A fix has been documented by @mstantoncook here [[2939] & [1651] How to solr-jetty JSP support](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2966)

Note the last comment, `sudo service jetty restart`

Answer (score 2):

### It's a Jetty BUG on Ubuntu 14.04!

There is nothing wrong with Ckan itself.

Actually, there is a bug in the `libjetty-extra-java` package (version 6.1.26 and newer) in Ubuntu 14.04. The bug was introduced after Jetty (in Ubuntu) has changed it's dependences from `libtomcat6-java` to `libtomcat7-java`.

You can get more info about this bug in Ubuntu Launchpad: [Bug #1508562 "Broken symlinks for JSP support in libjetty-extra-java version 6.1.26-1ubuntu1.1"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jetty/+bug/1508562).

The bug is already fixed on Debian, and I'm hope it will be solved in Ubuntu 14.04 soon.

### There are workarounds that may work for your case

I proposed some workarounds in this bug report, and since they can be useful for the Ckan users, I'll also replicate them here.

All of them consist on use both `jetty` and `libtomcat7-java`, but adding/replacing some classes (code ported from libtomcat6, in put in the `jsp-2.1-6.0.2.jar` file) to the Jetty classpath.

I don't know if they have some problem. Use them at your own risk!

#### Workaround 1 - Install the fix package proposed by vshn

I found this workaround here: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2966

In short:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~vshn/+archive/ubuntu/solr/+files/solr-jetty-jsp-fix_1.0.2_all.deb
dpkg -i solr-jetty-jsp-fix_1.0.2_all.deb
service jetty restart
```

This will install a JSP jar that works (the file will be named `jsp-2.1-6.0.2.jar`, but it contains classes ported from libtomcat6).

#### Workaround 2 - Manually install the JSP jar

Download the same JAR file that the DEB package above would install.

```
wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jetty/+bug/1508562/+attachment/4785985/+files/jsp-2.1-6.0.2.jar
```

Now, move it to a proper location inside the Jetty config dir. I did it this way:

```
mkdir /etc/jetty/extra-jars
mv jsp-2.1-6.0.2.jar /etc/jetty/extra-jars
```

And add a line like this one in the Jetty `start.config` file:

```
echo "/etc/jetty/extra-jars/jsp-2.1-6.0.2.jar" >> /etc/jetty/start.config
```

And:

```
service jetty restart
```

### Correct solution

The correct solution is to wait for the Ubuntu Team solution. However, while waiting for this fix, you can use any of the previous workarounds (I prefer the last one).

I hope they help you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps:

```
sudo mv jsp-2.1-6.0.2.jar /usr/share/jetty/lib/.
```

change own:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/share/jetty/lib/jsp-2.1-6.0.2.jar
```

finally restart jetty:

```
sudo service jetty restart
```

I followed this steps and now I can see localhost:8983/solr and localhost/solr/admin

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend, but i have bigger problems now. while trying to fix it, i tried to install Solr-tomacat and then use that with Ckan, but now i think that they are all messed up. nothing works and nothing can be uninstalled with out problems. i am stuck with two installations that neither work and have no clue about! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04 this can be fixed with:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://launchpad.net/~vshn/+archive/ubuntu/solr/+files/solr-jetty-jsp-fix_1.0.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i solr-jetty-jsp-fix_1.0.2_all.deb
sudo service jetty restart
```

Comment: All questions and answers are expected to be in English here

Comment: This exact solution has already been provided a year ago. Was it really necessary to state it again?

Answer (score 0):

Following http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.6/solr-setup.html#single-solr-instance 
(this one a bit old, but worked perfect for me )

You will have to edit `/etc/profile` and add this line to the end such as this to the end (adjusting the path for your machine’s jdk install:

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/` (or other version)

then

`export JAVA_HOME
sudo service jetty start`