# CKAN/Solr on Ubuntu: JSP not configured

Tags: jsp, ubuntu, solr, jetty, ckan

I am currently trying to set up CKAN on Ubuntu 14.04.03 (Desktop). I've been following these instructions: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html but have gotten stuck on the portion where I need to check and see if Solr is working. My Jetty installation appears to be working fine, as I get the "Welcome to Jetty 6 on Debian" page. However, if I navigation to my localhost url: localhost:8983/solr, I get the following error message:

**HTTP ERROR 500**
Problem accessing /solr/index.jsp. Reason:
JSP support not configured.

I have already done a bunch of research on this topic, including questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047288/ckan-solr-jsp-support-not-configured/34641609) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355839/ckan-local-installation-500-error-on-solr-jsp-support-not-configured), but have not been able to solve my problem with these solutions.

How do I configure my JSP support? I've already made sure to edit the JAVA_HOME setting in /etc/default/jetty so that it points to my Java installation, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the JSP support. Would it be best to completely re-do the installation process?

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: do you have variable JAVA_HOME in your export? `export -p | grep JAVA_HOME` I have same error on  ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 and can help you figure it out.

Comment: I have JAVA_HOME in production.ini... which I've set, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've also made sure to uncomment that line

Comment: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3562